# $\mathbb{Z}_6[x]$/$\langle2x-3\rangle$ isomorphic to what?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

To what common ring is $\mathbb{Z}_6[x]$/$\langle2x-3\rangle$ is isomorphic?

Obviously not $\mathbb{Z}_6[\frac{3}{2}]$...  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  It is isomorphic to itself, but I don't think that's the answer you want...

Comment: What does "common ring" mean here?

Comment: Which of $0,1,2,3,4,5,x,2x,3x,4x,5x,x^2, x^3, x^4$ are not turned into a lower degree polynomial or a smaller residue modulo 6?

Comment: You should use \langle and \rangle in place of < and > unless you are using < and > for inequalities.

Comment: @Gaffney No idea. I guess it just means it's not something exotic.

Comment: Whoever gave you this problem, you should ask them what a common ring is, because I don't think that's standard notation.

Comment: @EricTowers $0,1,2,3,4,5,x,3x,5x$?

Comment: I think the problem is "what is another way of expressing this ring". For example $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x - 1 \rangle$ is a fine description, but it's also isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, which would be the kind of answer they're looking for.

Comment: $3x= x + 2x = x + 3$.  So how many things are "untouched" by the ideal?  (They are, they're transmogrified into the new equivalence class containing them, but we can make the usual notational abuse.)

Comment: How about $x^2$?  Is there any multiple of $2x$ (in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$) that is $x^2$?  (If so, what does the quotient leave of $x^2$?  If not, does this give you 12 more elements?)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 6\!:\ (2x\!-\!3)(3x\!+\!2) \equiv x\,\Rightarrow \langle 2x\!-\!3\rangle\equiv \langle x,3\rangle\Rightarrow\,\Bbb Z_6[x]/\langle 2x\!-\!3\rangle=\Bbb Z_6[x]/\langle x,3\rangle\cong\ldots$

Comment: Can you please explain the first implication?

Comment: Clearly $\langle 2x-3 \rangle \le \langle x,3 \rangle$, and the equation shows that $x \in \langle 2x-3 \rangle$, which implies $3 \in \langle 2x-3 \rangle$, so $\langle x,3 \rangle \le \langle 2x-3 \rangle$.

Answer (score 3):

By the Chinese remainder theorem $\def\Z{\Bbb Z}\Z_6\cong\Z_2\times\Z_3$, and using the projections on the two factors your quotient becomes a product of quotients: $\Z_6[x]/\langle2x-3\rangle\cong\big(\Z_2[x]/\langle1\rangle\big)\times\big(\Z_3[x]/\langle-x\rangle\big)$. The first factor is the trivial ring and the second factor is just $\Z_3$. This uses $(R\times S)[x]\cong R[x]\times S[x]$, which is a generally valid identification via the obvious projections.

It might be good to give a bit more detail on how this argument works. Reducing modulo $2~$and$~3$ we find $2x-3\equiv1\pmod2$ respectively $2x-3\equiv-x\pmod2$, which one can write combined as $2x-3\equiv(1,-x)\pmod{2,3}$. But since the elements $1$ of the factors $\Z_2$ and $\Z_3$ respectively lift to $3\equiv(1,0)\pmod{2,3}$ and to $4\equiv(0,1)\pmod{2,3}$ in$~\Z_6$, these projections of $2x-3$ can also be represented by genuine multiples of it in $\Z_6[x]$, namely by $3\times(2x-3)=3$ and $4\times(2x-3)=2x$. Using multiples of the first of those one can see that any polynomial in $\Z_6[x]$ is congruent modulo $\langle2x-3\rangle$ to its projection to $\Z_3[x]$ inside $\Z_6[x]$ (this reflects the first factor being the trivial ring), and using the second of those that projection can be further reduced to its constant term (which is one of $0,2,4$ since elements of $\Z_3[x]\subset\Z_6[x]$ have even coefficients, but taking them modulo $3$ gives the more common representation as element of $\Z_3$).

Comment: Note that the opening sentence only works for the special case of computing $(R \times S) / (I \times J)$.

Comment: @Hurkyl: but isn't _every_ ideal of a product $R\times S$ of the form $I\times J$? In other words, the special case is not so very special, as far quotients of $\Z_n[x]$ are concerned.

Comment: You're right; I have Abelian groups on the mind. I'm not sure I've ever encountered a statement that rings have this weird property.